# VB.Net Break Foreach Loop

Tags: vb.net

How make an output like this:

English James Moore, Math Karen Hatskin, Science Quennie Orph
(using foreach loop ?)

i have this code -

```
dim T.Items.Add("James Morre","Karen Hatskin","Quennie Orph")
dim S.Items.Add("English","Math","Science")

For Each teacherItem as string In T.Items
  For Each subjectItem as string In S.Items

  Next
Next
```

---

Update:

```
  For Each teacherItem As String In tSub.Items
                Try
                    For Each subjectItem As String In avSub.Items
                        Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("insert into Student_Grade values('" & txt_lrn2.Text & "','" & txt_name.Text & "','" & txtgrade.Text & "','" & txtsection.Text & "','" & subjectItem.ToString & "','" & teacherItem.ToString & "',0,0,0,0,0,'" & SY.Text & "')", cn)
                            x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
                        End Using
                    Next
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Continue For
                End Try
            Next
```

but my output below is so redundant . .

[image: please click here for image]

Comment: Don't use nested `For Each` loops. Use a single `For` loop and then use the loop counter as an index into both collections.

Comment: how can i get the index of two collections ? any sample code ?

Comment: You don't "get" the index of any collection.  The loop counter IS the index.  If you can't find out how to get an item from a collection by index then you're not trying.  To do it for two collections you simply do it twice.

Comment: It would be really great if you used valid VB.NET syntax.

Comment: maybe my code is too complicated, but all want to get is an output like what i have mention above.

Comment: @Jerwen - Please don't edit your question so that it invalidates existing comments and/or answers. Always append to your question.

Comment: i have chnge my post, pls check

Comment: @Jerwen - Your update is confusing. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim T = {"James Morre", "Karen Hatskin", "Quennie Orph"}
Dim S = {"English", "Math", "Science"}

Dim n = Math.Min(T.Length, S.Length)

For i = 0 To n - 1
    Console.Write(S(i) & " " & T(i))
    If i < n - 1 Then
        Console.Write(", ")
    End If
Next
```

That gives:

```
English James Morre, Math Karen Hatskin, Science Quennie Orph
```

Alternatively, without using any loops, this works too:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", S.Zip(T, Function (x, y) x & " " & y)))
```

Comment: i have change my question for better reference . .